# Auto Logout Users in Android

Tags: android

I've looked at several examples, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

[Auto logout after 15 minutes due to inactivity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244915/auto-logout-after-15-minutes-due-to-inactivity-in-android)

After looking at that example, I created a LogoutService class that extends Service. Also, do I still have to have an intent that calls my login activity? Something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

My LogoutService Class

```
public class LogoutService extends Service {
public static CountDownTimer timer;
private final String TAG="Service";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        timer = new CountDownTimer(1 * 60 * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //Some code
                Log.v(TAG, "Service Started");
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                Log.v(TAG, "Call Logout by Service");
                // TODO should I create an Intent
                // my Login method here?
                stopSelf();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

And put this in all my other classes:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    try {
        LogoutService.timer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    LogoutService.timer.cancel();
}
```

But I keep getting a null pointer exception due to
    LogoutService.timer.cancel();

I surrounded it with an if statement that checks if it's null, but then nothing happens, not sure what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

> getting a null pointer exception due to LogoutService.timer.cancel();

Because `LogoutService` extends `Service` class but not starting it using `startService` method so `onCreate` method is not called and `timer` is `null`.

Do following :

1. Start/Stop service using `startService` and `stopService` methods
2. cancel timer in `onDestory()` of Service.
3. Add  `LogoutService` class as service in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Where should the start/stop methods go? In the LogoutService class?

Also, why onDestroy instead of onStop?

Comment: @Spider: in place of `LogoutService.timer.start();` and `LogoutService.timer.cancel();`

Comment: Not sure what that'd do. So just create a new method like this and call it?

    public void startService() {
        Logout.timer.start();
    }

Comment: Hey, can you please explain what you meant? Still can't figure this out